# Working with jQuery Collections

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to increase my understanding of jQuery. Please consider the following code.

```
if ($('.myClass').data('id') == '123') {
}
```

How does this work? It looks simple enough until you understand that `$()` returns a collection of elements. So what does the code above do exactly? How does it make sense to compare the value of the data-id attribute for a *collection* of elements like this?

(I understand I can use `each()` to explicitly test each element in the collection. My question is about what the code above does.)

Comment: `.data('id')` returns the value for the first item in the collection. Are you asking how to test whether _all_ items in the collection have that particular data value?

Comment: @nnnnnn + 1 but I think the OP was (rightly) commenting that it isn't clear from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) that `data(obj)` returned the value for the first matched element.

Comment: No, I'd have asked that if that's what I wanted to know. So perhaps you answered the question with the first part of your comment.

Comment: @RayToal - The [`.data()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) says that explicitly: _"Description: Returns value at named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value)."_

Comment: Yes of course it does say that if you scroll down!  But further up near the top of the page it says _".data( obj )
obj An object of key-value pairs of data to update."_  I know (and you know) that that isn't the actual form of `data` being used in this example, but it sure looks like it because it takes one parameter.  I was pointing out that this _can be considered confusing_ and hence was probably the reason the OP asked the question (because scrolling down would have uncovered the real answer quite easily :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.data('id')` returns the value for the first item in the collection, but `.data('id','xyz')` will set the value for all items in the collection - much the same behaviour as other jQuery methods like `.html()`, `.text()`, etc.

It may not seem to make sense to just test the first in an `if` statement like that, but it makes more sense for cases where you know there will be exactly one element, for example when your selector is an id, or when you use `$(this).data('id')` inside an event handler or something.

If you are asking how to test whether *all* items in the collection have a particular data value you can do this:

```
var $col = $('.myClass');
if ($col.length === $col.filter(function(){return $(this).data('id') === '123';}).length) {
   // do something
}
```

Or if you just want to know if at least one has that data value:

```
if ($('.myClass').filter(function(){return $(this).data('id') === '123';}).length > 0) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear. Okay, operating on the first item in the collection is cool. Not only is it easy to understand, but it behaves exactly as I would like it to.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you're trying to get a value through a jquery function, it returns the value from the first item in the collection. for example if you have:

```
<div class='1'></div>
<div class='2'></div>
<div class='3'></div>
```

and you run:

```
$('div').attr('class');
```

it will return "1". I don't know if this is uniform through all jQuery functions, but this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .each() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Example in comments since stackoverflow doesn't like jsFiddle that much.

Comment: Sorry, I guess there was some ambiguity in my question's wording. I've updated it to be more clear.